# массовая рассылка vkbottle

Tags: vkontakte-api

Есть следующий код:

```
@bp.on.private_message(FromAdmin(), text='mail <txt>')
    async def lsmsg(message: Message, txt):
        start_time = time.time()
        conversations = await bp.api.messages.get_conversations(count=200)
        for i in range(conversations.count):
            if conversations.items[i].conversation.peer.type == 'user':
                await bp.api.messages.send(peer_id=conversations.items[i].conversation.peer.id, random_id=0, message=txt)
        end_time = time.time()
        await message.answer(f'Рассылка завершена за {round(end_time-start_time, 1)} сек.')
```

Код необходим для массовой рассылки сообщений пользователям в ВК от имени группы. При его выполнении ошибок не происходит, просто приходит оповещение о том, что рассылка завершена, однако, сообщения пользователям не отправляются. Буду благодарен, если кто-то может направить меня в нужную сторону или помочь с исправлением.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ:**

Проблема в 6 строке.

```
if conversations.items[i].conversation.peer.type == "user":
    ...
```

Данное условие никогда не сработает как минимум из-за сравнения типа со строкой.

Конструкция имеет значения «MessagesConversationPeerType.GROUP», «MessagesConversationPeerType.USER» и так далее..

Правильным вариантом будет код ниже:

```
if conversations.items[i].conversation.peer.type.value == "user":
    ...
```

---

**Дополнение:**

Ещё ваш код сломается, если бот попробует отправить пользователю, который запретил писать сообщения, да и ожидать пока отправятся все сообщения придётся долго из-за одиночных запросов. Ниже привёл код, в котором решены данные проблемы.

```
async def send_message(user_id, text):
    allow_message = await bot.api.messages.is_messages_from_group_allowed(group_id=ИД_вашей_группы, user_id=user_id)
    if allow_message.is_allowed.value:
        await bot.api.messages.send(random_id=0, peer_id=user_id, message=text)


@bot.on.private_message(text='mail <text>')
async def mailing_handler(message: Message, text):
    start_time = time.time()

    conversations = await bot.api.messages.get_conversations(count=200)
    users_mailing = []

    for i in range(conversations.count):
        peer_type = conversations.items[i].conversation.peer.type.value
        if peer_type == 'user':
            user_id = conversations.items[i].conversation.peer.id
            users_mailing.append(asyncio.create_task(send_message(user_id=user_id, text=text)))

    await asyncio.gather(*users_mailing)

    end_time = time.time()

    await message.answer(f'Рассылка завершена за {round(end_time - start_time, 1)} сек.')
```